# Segmentation fault when doing strcpy

Tags: c, malloc, strcpy

I've started to learn C and I've been working on some small programs to learn. Right now I'm at the point with memory pointers and I have a quick question.

As I understand it, the program I've written below navigates to the /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/ directory and prints out the directories listed there. My intention is to allocate memory in the function getSysctlNames() and then deallocate it in the caller main(). getSysctlNames() should also return the number of directory names it found. I've read around that this isn't the best idea (allocate in the function and deallocate from the caller) but I'm just trying to fool around and learn rather than follow a pattern. My issue is that I obtain a segmentation fault at line 55 while running the strcpy function. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

```
int getSysctlNames(char** namesPointer);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char** namesPointer;
    int numberOfNames = getSysctlNames(namesPointer);
    printf("Number of files: %i\n", numberOfNames);
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= numberOfNames; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", namesPointer[i]);
        free(namesPointer[i]);

    }
    free(namesPointer);
    return 0;
}

int getSysctlNames(char** namesPointer) {
    int numberOfNames = 0;
    DIR *directory = opendir("/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/");
    if (directory) {
        struct dirent *directoryEntry;
        while ((directoryEntry = readdir(directory)) != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(directoryEntry->d_name, ".") != 0 &&
                strcmp(directoryEntry->d_name, "..") != 0) {
                numberOfNames++;
            }
        }
        closedir(directory);
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
    if (numberOfNames == 0) return 0;
    namesPointer = (char**) malloc(numberOfNames * sizeof(char*));
    if (namesPointer == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    directory = opendir("/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/");
    if (directory) {
        struct dirent *directoryEntry;
        int i = 0;
        while ((directoryEntry = readdir(directory)) != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(directoryEntry->d_name, ".") != 0 &&
                strcmp(directoryEntry->d_name, "..") != 0) {
                namesPointer[i] = malloc((strlen(directoryEntry->d_name) + 1) * sizeof(char));
                if (namesPointer[i] = NULL) {
                    int j = i - 1;
                    while (j >= 0) {
                        free(namesPointer[j]);
                        j--;
                    }
                    free(namesPointer);
                    return 0;
                }
                printf("%s\n", directoryEntry->d_name);
                strcpy(namesPointer[i], directoryEntry->d_name);
                printf("Got to 2\n");
                i++;
            }
        }
        closedir(directory);
        return numberOfNames;
    }
    free(namesPointer);
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I got as far as `int numberOfNames = getSysctlNames(namesPointer);`  .. this line is wrong as you pass an uninitialized variable to a function (this causes undefined behaviour).  Maybe you are missing that C uses *pass-by-value*  - a function receives a copy of its arguments.  With this in mind, review the rest of your code and you will clearly need to re-design your function calls

Comment: `if (namesPointer[i] = NULL)` is also a problem; if you use a modern compiler and enable warnings then the compiler would point out both of these problems for you

Comment: and even with the worst compiler in existence, `strcpy(&namesPointer[i],` should give a message telling you there is a problem. I guess you are either not reading the compiler output at all, or ignoring it

Comment: `if (namesPointer[i] = NULL)` is the problem. Passing an uninitialized variable in the function is not, but a sloppy programming that may cause a problem.

Comment: If you plan on using `namePointer` in `main` and you are not returning a pointer to it from your function, then  you need `char* namesPointer;` and the call being `int numberOfNames = getSysctlNames(&namesPointer);` (otherwise the function is simply operating on a copy of the *pointer-to-pointer-to-type*.) You can also keep the pointer to pointer to type with the same call, but then your declaration would require you to become a *3-star* programmer (not a complement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You allocate memory and then overwrite the pointer value with NULL:

```
namesPointer[i] = malloc((strlen(directoryEntry->d_name) + 1) * sizeof(char));
if (namesPointer[i] = NULL) {...
```

Should be

```
if (namesPointer[i] == NULL)
```

or

```
if (!namesPointer[i])
```

Comment: Thank you. Tired eyes seemed to be the cause here and I missed the extra equals sign

Comment: Some people would write `if (NULL == ptr)` to rely on compiler to pick this kind of error, but I don't like that. It looks ugly to me. Besides, modern compilers warns about that kind of problems.